# For Loop to create boxplots with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to loop through a list to create a series of boxplots using Matplotlib. Each item in the list should print a plot that has 2 boxplots, 1 using df1 data and 1 using df2 data.

I am successfully plotting x1, but x2 is blank and I don't know why.

I am using jupyter notebook with Python 3. Any help is appreciated!

```
df1 = df[df.order == 1]
df2 = df[df.order == 0]

lst = ['device', 'ship', 'bill']

i = 0

for item in lst:
    plt.figure(i)

    x1= df1[item].values
    x2 = df2[item].values

    plt.boxplot([x1, x2])
    plt.title(item)

    i = i+1
```

The series that I'm trying to plot have the following format with several thousand observations each:

**df[order] == 1**

```
df['device']      df['ship']      df['bill']
     0.0              0.0            0.0
    19.0              5.0            0.0
   237.0             237.0         237.0
```

**df[order] == 0**

```
df['device']      df['ship']      df['bill']
     1.0              21.0           0.0
    75.0              31.0         100.0
     5.0              18.0          71.0
```

The dataframe contains data for orders. The columns listed in `lst` is made up of dtype float64

Comment: What are the contents of `df`?

Comment: Thanks fuglede. Added the information to the original post

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of a value of `df` for which the described behavior occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it...there were a couple of NaN values appear to have prevented me from plotting.